# How can I convert a utf8 string to LATIN1 in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have many strings where the accents are converted wrongfully. I take those Strings from an API, so I cannot get them in other encoding formats. As an example, the string `é` returns as `Ã©` from the API. Is there any way I can convert these strings to show the accents correctly?

Comment: How do you make the call to this web api? If you e.g. are using dart:io you can just get the raw data and parse it manually with the correct charset.

Comment: Also, I am not sure your example are correct. `é` in UTF-8 translates into C3A9 which in latin1 would be `Ã©` and not `ã©` (E3A9). In fact, if you try parse `ã©` as UTF-8, it will just be parsed as invalid UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry, I inserted the ã© manually and forgot to capitalize the a. I'll edit it.

Comment: @julemand101 I'm using the [http/http.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to make the API call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can try something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const input = 'Ã©';
  final output = utf8.decode(latin1.encode(input), allowMalformed: true);
  print(output); // é
}
```

Alternative you can get the response from your web call as bytes by using `bodyBytes` on the response object:
https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html

And parse it with: `latin1.decode` or whatever charset the server are sending the the data as.